# iphone: NSDateFormatter how to show time in 24 hours format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter1=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"HHmmss MMddyyyy"];
NSDate *finalDate =[formatter1 dateFromString:testTime];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[lblpickUpTime setText:[formatter stringFromDate:finalDate]];
[formatter release];
[formatter1 release];
```

where testTime = @"201518 07122011"; and I want the result in 24 hours time

e.g. 20.15 rather than 8:15 PM

and is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try by setting

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];  // replacement for [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
```

**Alternate method (without using any formatters):**

```
NSRange range;
range.location = 2;
range.length = 2;
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",[myString substringToIndex:2],[myString substringWithRange:range]];
```

Comment: I only want time not the date

Comment: what about my second qutions that is there any better way to do this conversion as I made two formatters?

Comment: You can change the format of the 1st formatter itself. `[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];`. No need for the 2nd formatter.

Comment: @azar two conversion is must since u are converting a datestring on one format to another..

Comment: @akshay he is not converting from a date.. his input is also a string.. so your solution wont work

Comment: @azar: you can trim the first four char of the string.. if the time 1:00 am is come as 0100, then it would fine

Comment: @iAnand: The 2nd conversion is from a date to a string. I don't think it won't work.

Comment: @Akshay: it will work.. bt he want only time.. that i have answer.. then he want to know is there any alternative for not using two formatter.

Comment: Please note that if the user has 24 hour clock turned off on the device it will always return 8:15 PM, regardless of the format string you supply - [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you specify a format instead of using `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`, you can have the output in any format you want. For example:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];
[lblpickUpTime setText:[formatter stringFromDate:finalDate]];
[formatter release];
```